# How do I remove the comma at the end in python 3.7?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.7

What I get

```
'Left 2, Right 4, Right 2, '
```

What I want:

```
'Left 2, Right 4, Right 2'
```

My code:

```
def get_combination(decoded):
    #(eg: get_combination([-2, 4, 2])
    #create an empty string
    comb = ""
    #For each elment in [decoded] check if the elm is < 0 or elm is >= 0
    for elm in decoded:
        if elm >= 0: 
            #if the elm is greater than  0 add to the string comb
            # So the string will read (eg:Right 2) 
            comb += "Right " + str(abs(elm)) + ", "
        elif elm < 0:
            #if the elm is less than 0 add to the string comb
            #So the string will read (eg: Left 4)
            comb += "Left "+ str(abs(elm)) + ", "
    return comb
    #it returns 'Left 2, Right 4, Right 2, '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put commas until the end. The method [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is made just for you. It is called on the separator (like `', '`), and accepts an iterable of strings that you want to concentrate. For example:

```
def get_combination(decoded):
    def encode(x):
        if x < 0:
            return f'Left {abs(x)}'
        return f'Right {x}'
    return ', '.join(encode(x) for x in decoded)
```

The last line could be rewritten using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as

```
return ', '.join(map(encode, decoded))
```

If you want a really illegible one-liner (which I don't recommend, but python makes so easy to write):

```
', '.join(f'Left {abs(x)}' if x < 0 else f'Right {x}' for x in decoded)
```

or even (abusing f-strings to the max):

```
', '.join(f'{"Left" if x < 0 else "Right"} {abs(x)}' for x in decoded)
```

Comment: how would I do this In my case? cause im hella lost sorry :( I haven't even seen this before im in first year computer science 101(intro course)

Comment: @zing145. No worries. I've pointed you to some documentation and provided a drop-in replacement for your function. Let me know what's confusing you exactly and I'll help clarify what I can.

Comment: I was just confused on how encode works now I get it

Comment: @zing145. No problem. Glad you got it. You should select an answer if it works. By the way, your `elif` I'm the original question is unnecessary. You can just use `else`.

Answer (score 1):

To stick to what your Computer Science 101 has already taught you, you can instead append `", "` to `comb` at the beginning of the loop only if `comb` is not an empty string:

```
def get_combination(decoded):
    comb = ""
    for elm in decoded:
        if comb != "":
            comb += ", "
        if elm >= 0: 
            comb += "Right "
        else:
            comb += "Left "
        comb += str(abs(elm))
    return comb
```

Answer (score 0):

Or If you don't want to update your code you can use Strip method https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
def get_combination(decoded):
#(eg: get_combination([-2, 4, 2])
#create an empty string
comb = ""
#For each elment in [decoded] check if the elm is < 0 or elm is >= 0
for elm in decoded:
    if elm >= 0: 
        #if the elm is greater than  0 add to the string comb
        # So the string will read (eg:Right 2) 
        comb += "Right " + str(abs(elm)) + ", "
    elif elm < 0:
        #if the elm is less than 0 add to the string comb
        #So the string will read (eg: Left 4)
        comb += "Left "+ str(abs(elm)) + ", "
return comb.rstrip(", ")
```

Comment: Thanks, man I think this is what my professor wanted exactly lol